Hyper-V DDA doesn't support legacy PCI endpoints but it apparently works on my system. Are there any hidden problems?
My PC has SuperMicro H11SSL-i motherboard. It has 2 ASMedia USB 3.0 xHCI controllers which are displayed as legacy devices in Device Manager.
Device Manager Screen on Host
As expected, Survey-DDA.ps1 script reports them as "Not assignable".
Survey-DDA.ps1 Script Output
Anyway, I added -Force parameter to Dismount-VMHostAssignableDevice command and assigned it to VM. So far, it is working without any noticeable problem.
Device Manager Screen on VM
It makes me wondering whether there are any hidden problems? Like OS/hardware instability or security risks etc? Because when they don't support, there should be a reason.
How does PCIe legacy devices differ from regular (or should I say "modern"?) devices in the context of DDA? Is there anything I can check for this specific device (ASMedia USB Controller) to make sure that this won't cause problems?

It can be difficult to answer this sort of question because the "hidden problems" are likely to be rare and narrow and possibly only known by those who observe them. Also, this site requires that a post have a single, specific problem. Right now your post has perhaps 3 questions. Please pick one and EDIT your post to focus on that one.
